# Getting the value from cells in gridview

Tags: java, android

How can I get the value from any gridview cell, which items are only textviews? Also, I am looking for a way to do this outside the getView method in the adapter class and not in a onClick method as well. (Code sample answers would be highly appreciated). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Did not know that it bumps to the top, okay thanks !